# Azure DevOps task.setVariable in a powershell task with a loop sets only last variable value

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have powershell task in Azure DevOps pipeline and I am trying to remove double quotes from a bunch of variables spit out by arm template deployment. I cannot find a way to tell the "AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3" task NOT to add double quotes around the output values, so I added a powershell task after that to update those arm template variables in the pipeline so that I can remove the double quotes. As following task shows my powershell script. But the problem is when this task is finished and next task I have powershell to list all pipeline variables , which show me that only some variable values are updated randomly (sometimes one sometimes two sometimes another one sometimes another two) and all the other ones still have original value (with the double quotes). What am I doing wrong and why is this not updating all the values.

```
- pwsh: |
   Get-ChildItem ENV: | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'BicepOutput_FunctionNames'} | ForEach-Object { 
       $name = $_.Name
       $value =  $_.Value -replace '"', ''
       Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$name;]$value"
   }
```

Comment: Same issue over here, have you been able to solve this? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Regarding the quotes, you may find my answer to another question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77079584/2157640