# Access output values from azure devops bicep deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have an Azure Devops Release pipeline that has a ARM template deployment step.
It actually deploys a bicep file
The bicep has the following output -

```
output deployedItems array = [for (location, i) in locations: {
  item: module[i].outputs.app
}]
```

basically an array of objects from an earlier module
in an array because the earlier module gets called in a For loop, once for each location passed in to the bicep

this deploys fine

in the ARM template deployment step, i have the "Deployment outputs" set to bicepOutput

all good so far

now, in a later step i want to access a property from this output and this is where the wheels kinda come off the bus.

the output looks similar to this (edited for brevity) - `

```
"deployedItems": {
        "type": "Array",
        "value": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "apiVersion": "2023-01-01",
                    "location": "Australia East",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "testapp2".....
                     }
                 }
             }
         ]
```

i am trying the following to access the name of the item from the above snippet

$(bicepOutput.deployedItems[0].item.properties.name)

but this does nothing.
how do i get the value of this property from this output?

Comment: The output is going to be the JSON as a string, not a parsed JSON object. You'll need to convert the string into a JSON object to access properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the task is `string` format, you need to parse to JSON object using `ConvertFrom-Json` Powershell cmdlet in Powershell/Azure Powershell task and then that object can be used in same task or subsequent tasks.

From the task:

[image]

From the [task guide](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3#deployment-outputs):

[image]

Here is a similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76284563/14996050) with sample powershell for your reference.